# jquery crossfade - struggling to get a jquery crossfade effect to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is my css to handle my background images - I have the width and height set in another portion of my style sheet, so thats not the problem:

```
#mainphoto.bg1 { background-image:url(../images/site/homepg_img_1.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#mainphoto.bg2 { background-image:url(../images/site/homepg_img_2.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#mainphoto.bg3 { background-image:url(../images/site/homepg_img_3.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#mainphoto.bg4 { background-image:url(../images/site/homepg_img_4.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#mainphoto.bg5 { background-image:url(../images/site/homepg_img_5.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#mainphoto.bg6 { background-image:url(../images/site/homepg_img_6.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

My HTML is pretty basic:

```
 <div id="mainphoto">
       <div id="img-controls"></div>
 </div>
```

And then finally the jquery:

```
// create slidearray
 var slideArray = ["bg1", "bg2", "bg3", "bg4", "bg5", "bg6"];

        // add first image to the mainphoto panel 
        $('#mainphoto').addClass(slideArray[0]);

        // add the image navigation
        $('#img-controls').append('<ul id="mybg"></ul>');

        // get the slidelength
        var slideLength = slideArray.length;

        // create the loop and stuff
        for(i=0; i < slideLength; i++) {
            var slideText = i + 1;
            $('#mybg').append('<li class="bg'+slideText+'"><a href="#" rel="bg'+slideText+'"><img src="images/site/img-bullets.png" border="0" ></a></li>');
        }

        $('#mybg li a').bind('click', function(){
            var numSlide = $(this).attr('rel');
            var img2rem = $('#mainphoto').attr('class');

            $('#mainphoto').fadeOut('normal', function(){
                $('#mainphoto').addClass(numSlide).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    $('#mainphoto').removeClass(img2rem);                           
                });
            });

            $('#mybg li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            console.log("numslide: " +numSlide);
            console.log("img2rem: " +img2rem);

        });
```

So what i want it to do is a crossfade effect between the css classes I've made.  But basically what it does is the initial image fades out and then the new image fades in.  But i want those animations to occur at the same time creating a crossfade effect.

The next thing i want to do is make them autoplay so the user doesnt have to click on bullets to make the next image load.  I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Most of the jquery sliders i've seen use a  tag for the image but i have to use the images as background images because i have navigation and others things going on in the page that would make it otherwise complicated to use  tags. I'm just a little confused at the moment how to make this crossfade effect happen.  Much appreciated in advance for any assistance.

Comment: First of all you are missing an ending `</a>` inside your script. It's not possible, to overlay ONE element with two background images and fade symult. both of them. so sorry, but you are on the wrong way. I would create 2 main overlaying bg holders and than swap only the z-index higher one, changing bg sym. in both of them. A bit tricky to explain.

Comment: ok i fixed the closing </a>. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: eh, i just scrapped the way i was doing it and made a div with img tags in it, i just changed how it worked. I wanted to try to figure out how to use background images in the way i wanted to do it. But life is too short to waste so much time on such trivial details. Anyway, I'm in good shape now. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Nivoslider http://nivo.dev7studios.com/. it's a free to use jQuery Plugin that has a lot of cool transitions and even a autoplay feature. It will also spares you coding time..

Comment: But will it transition between images that are background images? that's what i was looking for.